# (How) Are lme4 mixed models hierarchical?

Tags: r, lme4-nlme, multilevel-analysis

This is a very basic/stupid question, but it's even more stupid not to ask.

Are multilevel models defined using lme4 hierarchical? (say:)

```
outcome ~ predictor + (predictor|subject)
```

That is, do the fixed effects estimates at the group level drive the single-subject random slopes? (As does shrinking in Bayesian hierarchical modelling). If so, how exactly?

In practical terms, is it valid to interpret individual random slopes effects as independent observations?

When looking at model definitions I don't expect to see any hierarchical effects, but then why would one not do many independent regressions and then integrate them 'by hand'?